# Access model defined in manifest

Tags: sapui5

Using single model definition in manifest.json

```
"models": {
    "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
            "bundleName": "....i18n.i18n"
        }
    },
    "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService"
    }
}
```

i can bind to model from XML and it's work

```
<List items="{path: '/myOneSet'}"> ... </List>
<List items="{path: '/myTwoSet'}"> ... </List>
```

but i can not access to it from code

```
this.getView().getModel().getProperty('/myOneSet')
```

or

```
this.getView().getModel().getProperty('/myOneSet/>param')
```

not work. How it accessible?

Comment: Are you calling your model in onInit?

Comment: If you are trying to access the model in `onInit`, you must be getting the error message in the console saying `getProperty` cannot be called from `undefined`. Is that what you get? Or what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If `mainService` is an OData service, then your model is an ODataModel. You can access data via methods described in the [API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods), e.g.: [read()](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read)

```
this.getView().getModel().read('/myOneSet', {
    success: function(oData, response) {
        // do sg. with oData
    }
});
```

Most of its data access methods has a second parameter-object with a success function callback. This function will be called asynchronously with the data on the given path upon successful data retrieval from the datasource. Most of the ODataModel API methods works with callbacks. You can read more about callbacks [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Answer (score 0):

If you defined model in the manifest.json file then you can access it via Component. If you created your project via template then you have a **BaseController.js** file which is the ancestor of your other controllers and there is a function **getComponentModel**. So, I would suggest you to try this code in your controller:

```
this.getComponentModel().getProperty('/myOneSet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the property name that you try to access I assume you are using an ODataModel. Is that correct?

If that's true you have to consider a few things... [ODataModel.getProperty()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#getProperty) does not trigger requests. Instead it will return whats already available. If you want to trigger a request you should execute an [ODataModel.read()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read). If you want to get the loaded data from the ODataModel then you should also know **when** the data has been loaded. This you can achieve by attaching a change event handler when you do the binding.

Instead of describing how to access the data of an ODataModel I wrote s little [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/ratapubodi/edit?html,output) for you (or see below). Just check the change event handler. There are multiple ways to access the data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->
 
        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
 
                <Table
                    id="myTable"
                    growing="true"
                    growingThreshold="10"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    busyIndicatorDelay="0">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Orders of ALFKI"/>
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="OrderID"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Order Date"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="To Name"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Ship City"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <!-- filled via bindItems() in controller -->
                    </items>
                </Table>
 
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
 
        <!-- XML Fragment -->
        <script id="myXMLFragment" type="ui5/fragment">
            <core:FragmentDefinition
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
                <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                    <cells>
                        <ObjectIdentifier title="{OrderID}"/>
 
                        <Text
                            text="{
                                path:'OrderDate',
                                type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true}
                            }"/>
 
                        <Text text="{ShipName}"/>
 
                        <Text text="{ShipCity}"/>
 
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </core:FragmentDefinition>
        </script>
 
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
 
                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
                ], function (Controller, ODataModel) {
                    "use strict";
 
                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () {
                            this.getView().setModel(
                                new ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", {
                                    json : true,
                                    useBatch : false
                                })
                            );
 
                            var sPath = "/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders";
                            var oTable = this.byId("myTable");
                            var oTemplate =  sap.ui.xmlfragment({
                                fragmentContent : jQuery("#myXMLFragment").html()
                            });                              
                            
                            oTable.bindItems({
                              path : sPath,
                              template : oTemplate,
                              templateShareable : false,
                              sorter : null, 
                              filters : null,
                              events : {
                                change : function (oEvent) {
                                  var oModel, oListBnd, aContexts, i, oObj;
                                  
                                  console.log("1. Example: ODataModel.getProperty() does not trigger a request (but here we have the data already)!");
                                  oModel = this.getView().getModel();
                                  console.dir( oModel.getProperty("/Orders(10643)"));  //OK
                                  console.dir( oModel.getProperty("/Orders") );       //Not OK
                                  console.dir( oModel.getData("/") );             //DANGER: Could contain different entities!!!!!
                                  
                                  console.log("2. Example: Accessing the Data via ListBinding");
                                  oListBnd = oTable.getBinding("items");      // get the ListBinding
                                  //oListBnd = oEvent.getSource();                // this works here inside the change handler
                                  aContexts = oListBnd.getCurrentContexts();  // the the contexts
                                  for(i=0; i<aContexts.length; i++){
                                    oObj = aContexts[i].getObject();   // access the items/objects
                                    console.dir( oObj ); 
                                  }                                  
                                  
                                }.bind(this)
                              }
                            });
                          
                        }
                    });
                });
 
                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
 
            });
        </script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Just declare this is manifest

```js
"models": {
 "createMod": {
    "preload": true,
    "dataSource": "CreateService",
    "settings": {
    }
}
```

and Try to Access by Controller using.
var oModelCheck = that.getOwnerComponent().getModel("createMod");